# emails in posts

Tags: discussion, flagging, review, new-users

hi I was reviewing https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/180248 (also )
[How to find an ellipse , given 2 passing points and the tangents at them?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109890/how-to-find-an-ellipse-given-2-passing-points-and-the-tangents-at-them)
and the new poster gave his email address in the answer, at the moment I just flagged it (was this the right action?) the post because of this but what is the general opinion on this? 
- should we remove it,?
- warn the poster about it? (it is a first answer of a new user)

or something else?

Comment: the question is, why writing the email? I'm curious too to know some opinions

Comment: I noticed the same post, on a two year old Question.  Taken at face value the user wants to know if their solution was useful, so I left a comment suggesting the benefits of registration and putting some contact info, if they wish, into a user profile.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on the context. If the answer ends with "Cheapp j0rdan shoes! yg59drhey@yahoo.com" then you should certainly flag. But in this case, the reason appears to be benign: the answerer welcomes email in case of follow-up questions. Maybe s/he does not plan on visiting SE again (which would be sad, but it's their choice). I would let it be.

Comment: Yes, please flag in the above case. Some of the moderators would be very interested in inexpensive jays.

Comment: I'd always wondered how best to show my appreciation for the moderators' efforts.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber What is a "J"?